# USB Dock (Pluggable UD3900) video stopped working

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, displaylink

Been using a Pluggable UD3900 (displaylink chipset) for over two years without issues.  Today, the video out stopped working.  Checked all cables and tried a windows laptop - the dock is working as expected on Windows.  Under 18.04 LTS with kernel 5.3.0-7625-generic, and Intel HD 620 onboard graphics, the usb display stopped working.

No external monitor detected, even with randr.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please run `sudo lsusb`, copy the results, come back here, click [edit], and paste the results at the end of your question. More info on lsusb is found at https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/lsusb.8.html

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.  Something went horribly wrong with the odiaf ppa updates - I reinstalled the OS and Xorg is now working with the dock (multiple monitors) as expected.